# Why do we minimize the squared norm instead of the norm in this optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

When reading about the optimization problem for Support Vector Machine in Bishop's book ([Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/)) he wrote that:

> The optimization problem then simply requires that we maximize $\| \mathbf w\|^{-1}$ which is equivalent to
>   minimizing $\| \mathbf w\|^{2}$

Here $\| \mathbf w\|$ is the euclidian norm of the vector $\mathbf w$ so it is always a positive number.

I am wondering why do we  not minimize $\| \mathbf w\|$ instead of  $\| \mathbf w\|^2$ ?

Does using $\| \mathbf w\|^{2}$ simplifies the optimization problem?

At first I thought that taking the square made the problem convex, but the function $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ looks convex to me too.

Comment: Minimizing $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ and minimizing $\lVert\cdot\rVert^2$ are the same thing, aren't they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Minimizing $|w|$ is the same as minimizing $|w|^2$. As I understand it, the reason we choose the latter is purely for convenience. Would you rather deal with partials of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ or $x^2+y^2$? The latter, obviously, because it's easier.

Comment: And its derivative is well defined.